# Galaxy Tab 10.1 & ACR122U NFC RFID reader - Driver

Tags: kernel, driver, nfc, rfid, pcsc

I'm developping android application for sansung galaxy tab 10.1 and NFC reader (ACR 122U) usb

When I plug-in the usb (qith the usb adapter kit sansung) and run dmesg in root mode I give this error:

```
usb usb2: New usb device found, idVendor 1d6b idProduct=0002
usb usb2:  New Usb device String:Mfr=3 Product=2 SerialNumber=1
Product Tetra EHCI Host Controller
Manufacturer Linux 2.6.36.3 ehci_hcd
serialNumber tegra-ehci.0
hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detect
....
....
...
...

usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using tegra-ehci and address 2
usb 2-1: decvice v072f p2200 is not supported
host_notify: ndev name=tegra-ehci.0 from state=0 -> to state=5
hub 2.0:1.0 unable to enumerate USB device on port 1

usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using tegra-ehci and address 3
usb 2-1: decvice v072f p2200 is not supported
etc....
...
```

Can you guys help me?

I think that the driver is not present... How I can do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May want to check here since this seems to have been answered already. In short,
the android OS on tablets doesn't contain (isn't built with) the NFC drivers.
You may get USB to recognize the device, but android kernel won't know how to 
control the hardware itself.

[How to Connect External NFC Card Reader to Tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451411/how-to-connect-external-nfc-card-reader-to-tabletandroid-2-3-3)