# Does android.nfc package works with tablets

Tags: tablet, nfc, android, tablet-pc

What i want to do is connect a NFC
reader to the USB of a tablet. So what i want to know first of all is
if its possible, if it is possible what brand and model of  NFC and
tablet should i buy and what version of android is required to use
`android.nfc` package.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9457312/1202968

Answer (score 0):

The tablet needs to have android 2.3 or higher and a USB port in your case

But as far as I know there are nor commercial android tablets with NFC chip.

In theory it should work, although I can't confirm if a usb NFC reader will work.
Also there is a difference between a NFC 'tag' and NFC 'reader'. I know that since android 2.3 NFC tags shouldn't be a problem, I can't confirm the reader though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it works perfectly with tablet.NFC support are there in api but its upto tablet manufacturer