# NFC reader with tablet

Tags: nfc, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Connect External NFC Card Reader to Tablet(Android 2.3.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451411/how-to-connect-external-nfc-card-reader-to-tabletandroid-2-3-3)

This is may be the duplication of this

[How to Connect External NFC Card Reader to Tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451411/how-to-connect-external-nfc-card-reader-to-tabletandroid-2-3-3/10895247#10895247)

I want to connect the nfc USB reader of http://www.sensorid.it/en/products/stickid.html

with a tablet running android OS 3.2. I need to read the nfc tags using my app and above mention NFC reader.

I am not able to conclude any thing so far. Is this possible or not? 
If yes, what should be the starting point for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research..my conclusion is that we can not talk with NFC reader without the help of manufacturers, as they knows how to communicate with it..what protocol they use.

So the solution of my problem is to USE a NFC reader which is HID compatible.

Like one I found at http://www.rsdm-systems.de/products/de/RFID-Systeme-LF-HF/RFID-Sticks/RFID-Stick-Mifare-Classic-USB.html

This solved my problem.

Comment: this can be plugged into any android device with USB host is it?

Comment: Yes any android device which have USB host, it will give output in a edit Text.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly will not be able to use it directly.

1. 3.2 supports host functionality, so it will recognize a USB device.
2. I doubt if your reader will be able to talk directly to the OS as there are in between layers which it has to go through before it can be read and converted into OS understandable values.
3. You should talk to the manufacturers to see if they have found a way. Then yyou should go ahead and buy it.

Comment: I know 3.2 supports host functionality. Your second point is valid...I need bare USB communication with NFC reader, and no NFC reader on market available which uses bare USB communication.

Talking to manufactures also not worked.

Comment: You could however write your own JNI classes to interface with the Nfc.apk

Or, the bleeding edge linux kernels have support for NFC. You could somehow try integrating that to whatever device you are using!

Comment: I also try to modify the Kernel and try to add openNFC library in it, but failed. Because compiling the kernel for a device is not a easy task.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016147/huawei-mediapad-custom-rom