# Accessing card-emulation mode on USB-NFC-Reader

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, ndef, hce

I have an Android tablet with Android 4.2. This tablet does not have NFC hardware. However I have an external USB reader: [ACR 1252U](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/342/acr1252u-usb-nfc-reader-iii-nfc-forum-certified-reader/), that came with an [Android library](http://android.acs.com.hk/). I have asked some general questions of my setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496019/android-nfc-with-usb-nfc-reader). Now that it gets more specific, I need to ask another one. In this previous question I found out, that I can use the *ACS Android library* to access the readers **card emulation** capabilities.

My first goal is to make that reader emulate an NFC tag, that contains a URL. Any NFC-capable Android phone should be able to scan this emulated tag and automatically open the browser. I have tested it, and it works with a real (physical) tag. But unfortunately I am not able to emulate this tag correctly...

Now I wrote an Android application, but I am stuck. According to the [readers API (PDF)](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/6402/API-ACR1252U-1.08.pdf), I can get it into card emulation mode by sending the command

```
E0 00 00 40 03 01 00 00
```

When I do this, it gives me the answer:

```
E1 00 00 00 03 01 01 01
```

This confirms, that it is in card emulation mode. With an Android application I now can scan the emulated Tag, which says, that this is recognized as a "NXP MIFARE Ultralight" tag.

My problem now is, how to feed the tag with a URL. According to the reader API (section 5.10.3), I need to send the command:

```
E0 00 00 60 13 01 01 00 0F D1 01 0B 55 01 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D
```

where `D1 01 0B 55 01 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D` is the NDEF message that contains the URL "http://www.google.com". I created this NDEF message using this Android Java code:

```
String target_url = "http://www.google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(target_url);
NdefRecord recordNFC = NdefRecord.createUri(uri);
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(recordNFC);
```

An application on my Android phone, that reads NFC tag says the following:

[image]

As you can see, the URL is saved on the emulated tag.

- So why doesn't the browser of my phone open the url?
- Am I missing something? Are my commands wrong?
- Why are there some "?" characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command that you are using,

```
E0 00 00 60 <Lc> 01 01 <Byte address> <Length> <Data>
```

writes data bytes starting at block 3 of the emulated NFC Forum Type 2 tag. Thus, the byte address `0x00` addresses the first byte of block 3.

The problem that you are facing is that you only write the NDEF message itself starting at block 3 (byte 0). However, an NFC Forum Type 2 tag needs further metadata. Specifically, block 3 is the capability container block. For the specific memory layout presented by the ACR1252U, the CC block would need to be filled with the value

- `E1 10 06 00` (if write access should be allowed) or
- `E1 10 06 0F` (if other NFC devices should treat the tag as read-only).

`E1` is the magic number indicating that this is an NFC Forum tag, `10` refers to version 1.0 (the current version) of the data mapping defined by the NFC Forum Type 2 Tag Operation specification, and `06` indicates that the tag has a total of 12 data blocks.

Further, you need to wrap the NDEF message into an NDEF Message TLV block. The NDEF Message TLV block has the tag `0x03`. Thus, the wrapped NDEF message would look like this:

```
03 0F D1010B5501676F6F676C652E636F6D
```

The tag memory, that you need to write would therefore look like this:

```
E1 10 06 00
03 0F D1 01
0B 55 01 67
6F 6F 67 6C
65 2E 63 6F
6D
```

Finally, you should fill the tag memory to full blocks by placing a Terminator TLV (tag `0xFE`, no length) at the end and filling the remaining bytes with zeros (`0x00`). This also applies to the case where the data is already aligned to full blocks but there is further (empty) blocks beyond the end of your data.

```
E1 10 06 00
03 0F D1 01
0B 55 01 67
6F 6F 67 6C
65 2E 63 6F
6D FE 00 00
```

Thus, you would want to use the following write command to store the data on the emulated Type 2 tag:

```
E0 00 00 60 1C 01 01 00 18 E1 10 06 00 03 0F D1 01 0B 55 01 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D FE 00 00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This question was pretty long ago. The project was abandoned ever since by the project manager. Nevertheless I will accept it, because it seems very good. For future readers: Be aware, I have never tested it ;)