# How to make a iphone act as nfc tag

Tags: iphone, nfc, payment

is there way in witch I can make my iphone act as passive nfc tag when it come never a specific phone or EPOS payment terminal . As Apple Pay is banned in Indian want to build a alternative tap to pay system for iPhone .
Thank you

Comment: As Apple limits the access to the NFC interface you probably can't do this, sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this possible to send NFC signal from NFC read/writer to Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073388/is-this-possible-to-send-nfc-signal-from-nfc-read-writer-to-iphone)