# Adding external NFC reader to RCA Voyager

Tags: android, nfc, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an [RCA Voyager 3](https://www.cnet.com/products/rca-voyager-iii/specs/) that does not have NFC.  I am using it for my [kegbot tablet](https://github.com/Kegbot/kegbot-android) and would like to use the NFC authentication capability it has.  I have an OTG cable and I would like to purchase a separate NFC USB adapter to connect via the OTG cable.

I found the [kegbot android app](https://github.com/Kegbot/kegbot-android) uses the `android.nfc` library, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451411/how-to-connect-external-nfc-card-reader-to-tablet) (a 7 yr old post) that if a tablet does not ship with NFC capability "The Android NFC API is essentially an empty stub implementation" and no amount of software will make it work.

If I buy an NFC USB cable and connect it up will it work?  If not will it work if I use a custom ROM?

Comment: The answer that you found is still valid. The Android NFC API will only be usable for built-in NFC hardware. Obviously, if you build your own OS (custom ROM), you may be able to add any functionality you need. Hence, you could add your own implementation of the Android NFC API that plugs into your USB NFC reader.

Comment: thanks.  I just was checking to see if it changed